# When should I use stored procedure or function?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know when I should use stored procedure. I assume that I have the query like this:

```
select * from table A
```

Or

```
Update A set .....
```

Or

```
Insert into A...
```

Should I use stored procedure for the query like above or not. If not, so when should I use stored procedure?

I'm working on a big project and I'm a leader. At the moment, our website is well but I know that It will be die in the future. So I want to convert all complicated query to stored procedure, but I have to choose which query I should convert.

Comment: When you need it, you'll know. Until then, do not worry about it.

Comment: Maybe when a query takes a long time, I will consider whether I should use stored procedure or not. But I actually want to know about this thing, I assume that table A contains a huge data in it. So what will i do?

Comment: Feel free to up vote an answer if you like it :) @jewelInguyen8

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with "huge data" or queries taking "a long time". It's about when you need to perform more complex operations than a single INSERT or SELECT and you need to perform them more than once, and it makes sense to have these operations stored for re-use inside your database rather than written in code in your own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2014, for [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) functions (`INSERT - SELECT - UPDATE - DELETE`) you should use an `ORM` to create a code representation of the data model.

If you need to perform a lot of complex SQL statements from a small set of input or if you you need to push thousands of records to SQL in a single statement, I would recommend you to use Stored Procedure.

Some people will probably talk about speed of stored proc. A decade ago, It was true about the speed but now, in most of time, there's no performance gain by using a `SP`.

Take a look to that article: http://kevinlawry.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/why-i-avoid-stored-procedures-and-you-should-too/